# when user deactivate assign case to queue in test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
 public class Helper {

    @future
    public static void dummyUsers(Set<Id> userIds) 
    {
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think you would be better off creating a [`Schedulable apex`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) class to periodically check for Inactive users with Cases assigned to them? I mean, I am not sure about your business requirement, but seems more appropriate, what say you? :)

Comment: business requirement is when user leaving company then his/ her pending cases assign to existing queue this is achieved functionality working. issue is that in test class need to check in assert that assign cases queue or not , test class is also worked and covered 96%. but client want proper assert in test class. so need to check these thing only could you please help

Comment: You need a Test.stopTest() to trigger async methods and then you can assert thereafter. `seealldata=true` should not be required here

Answer (score 0):

You can assert by using Owner type field of inserted case records. Put assert statement as:

```
Test.startTest();
update u;
Test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals([SELECT Id, Owner.Type 
                    FROM Case 
                    WHERE Id = :caseList[0].Id][0].Owner.Type,
                    'Queue');
```

Note: Put `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` methods to assert future methods.

Comment: @cloudZigZag is this a handler class for any trigger?

Comment: @cloudZigZag Put `test.startTest();` and `test.stopTest();`. Then place `update u;`  between them.

Comment: @cloudZigZag can you check updated answer and what you are getting in actual and expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53930/discussion-between-reshma-and-cloudzigzag).

Answer (score 0):

I would have checked two things in my test class

> After creating case
>   Check the owner Id of the case

```
System.assert(testCase.OwnerId==u.Id, 'Owner Id matched!');
```

> Second, I would check the Owner of the case after deactivating the **User**

```
caseList = [SELECT id, OwnerId FROM Case WHERE id in: caseList];

System.assertNotEquals(caseList[0].OwnerId, u.id, 'Case owner changed!');
```

Or you could check to see if the owner of case is changed to **Queue**

```
RoutingSettings__c rsTest = RoutingSettings__c.getInstance(u.ProfileId);
System.assertEquals(rs.StandardRoutingQueueId__c;, caseList[0].OwnerId, 'Case owner is Queue!');
```

Comment: alternative to checking owner is queue: `system.assertEquals(Group.SobjectType,caseList[0].OwnerId.getSobjectType(),'sb owned by q');`